# Rxjava Filtering the duplicate item in List

Tags: android, database, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using RxJava and Retrofit in My App.Here's the setup of the app.When the app is launched the app make two request one to the database and other to the Network Api (using Retrofit) and both request return a `Observable<List<Article>>`. So what I did is basically merged the two Observable. Now the problem is sometimes the network return Articles that are already present in the Database. So how do I filter out the duplicate item from the List. Here's my Code.

```
return Observable.merge(dataSource.getArticles(source), remoteSource.getArticles(source))
            .distinct();
```

So I tried distinct operator but it's not filtering the Articles out.Here's the output looks like form db.

```
Article1
Article2
Article3
Article4
```

Output from Network

```
Article7
Articke8
Article3
Article4
```

What I want is a distinct list of Article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `Article` has proper `equals` implementation,

you could collect them into a set:

```
 dataSource.getArticles(source)
    .mergeWith(remoteSource.getArticles(source))
    .collect(HashSet::new, (set, list) -> set.addAll(list))
```

or you could unroll each list and apply `distinct` followed by `toList`:

```
 dataSource.getArticles(source)
    .mergeWith(remoteSource.getArticles(source))
    .flatMapIterable(v -> v)
    .distinct()
    .toList()
```

Comment: your answer say gives error that the return type of `toList()` is `Single`

Comment: So you're using RxJava2. A simple `.toObservable()` will be enough

Answer (score 0):

That's because they are returning different **lists**. So the `distinct` method recognize them as different items

If you want to emit first the database items and then add the server ones... This may be a bit more complex but not too much ;)

```
Observable<List<Article>> databaseArticles = ...
Observable<List<Article>> serverArticles = ...
Observable<List<Article>> allArticles =
    Observable.combineLatest(
        databaseArticles,
        serverArticles
            .startWith(emptyList()),         // so it doesn't have to wait until server response
        (dbItems, sItems) => {
            // Combine both lists without duplicates
            // e.g.
            Set<Article> all = new HashSet<>();
            Collections.addAll(all, dbItems);
            Collections.addAll(all, sItems);
            return new ArrayList<>(all);
        });
```

Comment: `(dbItems, sItems) => {}`Is this the BiFunction

Comment: I don't remember the exact erasure but it's probably it. `combineLatest` receives some observables and a function that combines the emitted values